# undo redo in standalone Aptana Studio 3

Tags: aptana

Is there a way to get Undo and Redo buttons into the toolbar in the standalone version of Aptana Studio 3?

The control Z does not appear to work for undo and there does not appear to be a shortcut for Redo.

Comment: A specific editor (or file extension) is not working for you, or all editors?

Comment: You can customize shortcuts from Windows>Preferences>General>Editors>key you can search there for undo/redo and can customize as you want.

Answer (score 1):

I havent found buttons ... but you have a couple of keyboards commands for that :

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> => undo
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> => redo

Hope this help, e must rebind <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> as i'm used to ... but <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> will do the same from std intallation